# Very Simple dot file cannot be converted to png by Graphviz twopi

Tags: graphviz

I am using graphviz twopi to generate a png file. I have many dot files but only three which cannot be converted to png. Below is one simplified example which cannot be converted:

```
digraph G{
    overlap = false;
    splines = true;
    root = "a";
    "a" [label ="ATCC 12633"];
    "b" [label = "R M Egan",fontsize=25];
    "a" -> "b" [label = "paper:1",penwidth = 4,color = black ,len=2];
    "c" [fontsize=25, label = "ATCC 8014"];
    "b" -> "c" [label = "paper:1"];
}
```

I use -v to see the details, which are:

```
mongodb@mongodb:/home/wuchang/newStore/allYear$ sudo twopi ATCC_12633_1977.dot -Tpng -o 77.png -v
twopi - graphviz version 2.26.3 (20100126.1600)
Activated plugin library: libgvplugin_pango.so.6
Using textlayout: textlayout:cairo
Activated plugin library: libgvplugin_neato_layout.so.6
Using layout: twopi:neato_layout
Using render: cairo:cairo
Using device: png:cairo:cairo
The plugin configuration file:
        /usr/lib/graphviz/config6
                was successfully loaded.
    render      :  cairo dot fig gd map ps svg tk vml vrml xdot
    layout      :  circo dot fdp neato nop nop1 nop2 osage patchwork sfdp twopi
    textlayout  :  textlayout
    device      :  canon cmap cmapx cmapx_np dot eps fig gd gd2 gif gv imap imap_np ismap jpe jpeg jpg pdf plain plain-ext png ps ps2 svg svgz tk vml vmlz vrml wbmp x11 xdot xlib
    loadimage   :  (lib) eps gd gd2 gif jpe jpeg jpg png ps svg
fontname: "Times-Roman" resolved to: (ps:pango  Times Roman,) (PangoCairoFcFont) "DejaVu Sans 14" 
root = a
Rank separation = 0.000 1.000 2.000 
Adjusting G using Voronoi
Node separation: add=1 (4.000000,4.000000)
```

I doubt it is just a bug in graphviz. My graphviz version is 2.26.3, my OS is Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS.

Compared with a successfully-converted dot file whose convertion output is:

```
mongodb@mongodb:/home/wuchang/newStore/allYear$ sudo twopi ATCC_12633_1988.dot -Tpng -o 88.png -v
twopi - graphviz version 2.26.3 (20100126.1600)
Activated plugin library: libgvplugin_pango.so.6
Using textlayout: textlayout:cairo
Activated plugin library: libgvplugin_neato_layout.so.6
Using layout: twopi:neato_layout
Using render: cairo:cairo
Using device: png:cairo:cairo
The plugin configuration file:
        /usr/lib/graphviz/config6
                was successfully loaded.
    render      :  cairo dot fig gd map ps svg tk vml vrml xdot
    layout      :  circo dot fdp neato nop nop1 nop2 osage patchwork sfdp twopi
    textlayout  :  textlayout
    device      :  canon cmap cmapx cmapx_np dot eps fig gd gd2 gif gv imap imap_np ismap jpe jpeg jpg pdf plain plain-ext png ps ps2 svg svgz tk vml vmlz vrml wbmp x11 xdot xlib
    loadimage   :  (lib) eps gd gd2 gif jpe jpeg jpg png ps svg
fontname: "Times New Roman Bold" resolved to: (PangoCairoFcFont) "DejaVu Sans Bold 30" 
fontname: "Times-Roman" resolved to: (ps:pango  Times Roman,) (PangoCairoFcFont) "DejaVu Sans 24.9990234375" 
root = -290487096
Rank separation = 0.000 1.000 2.000 
Adjusting G using Voronoi
Node separation: add=1 (4.000000,4.000000)
Number of iterations = 5
Number of increases = 3
Edge separation: add=1 (3.200000,3.200000)
Creating edges using splines
Using render: cairo:cairo
Using device: png:cairo:cairo
twopi: allocating a 1477K cairo image surface (907 x 417 pixels)
```

I tried many many modifications such as:

1. If I remove `overlap=false`, it can generate the png file but the
   generated graph's node is overlapped, which doesn't meet my
   requirement.
2. When I remove `fontsize = 23` for node "c", it also
       can generate the png file, but the png file is completely
       wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest updating to a newer version of Graphviz. There has been a lot of development in the last four years. Because your verbose output ends before the number of iterations is displayed, I strongly suspect it's a bug (maybe an infinite loop) the version of Graphviz you're using.

Using 2.36.0 under OS X, your file gives me this (which is obviously not what you want):

[image: original version]

If I comment out the line `root = "a";` I get this:

[image: with root commented out]